Electrostatic separation of two spheres suspended by strings
This is a question about Example 23.4 in Serway and Jewitt, p. 698 in my edition 1.
The two spheres are in equilibrium, separated by an electrostatic force due to an identical positive charge q+ on each sphere. The spheres have small identical mass m, so there is a small downward/inward force due to gravity tending to close the distance r = 2a between the spheres. The angle $\theta$ is small (5 degrees).
My question is this: the text expresses the equilibrium as $F_e = mg \tan \theta,$ and uses this to solve for q+. But the distance r is being maintained by the electrostatic force and opposed at both ends by the gravitational force. Shouldn't the equilibrium expression be $F_e = 2 mg \tan \theta$ ?
If the mass of either sphere were slightly decreased, the distance r would increase. In a sense, the repulsive separation is being "squeezed" between the two masses, and so the total gravitational force is (?) $2~ mg~ \tan \theta $
I assume the text is right, but would like to know why we do not take both masses into consideration in writing the sum of forces and solving for q.


Serway and Jewitt, Physics for Scientists and Engineers, 8th Ed (Cengage, 2014)


Your confusion is that: either you could write the equation of force balance for the relative distance $\vec r=\vec{r}_1-\vec{r}_2$ or for a single body, say $\vec{r}_1$. If you choose to write for the body $1$, you will consider only forces applied over the body $1$, so one electric force and one gravitational force. If you want to analyse it to the point of view of the relative distance, both electrical forces contribute to increase it, both gravitational forces contribute to decrease it. Either cases, however, are equivalent. In the relative distance case, you would balance $2F_e$ with $2mg\tan\theta$.

A less hand-waving derivation of this result could be achieved by considering the torque equation over two spheres
$$
\begin{aligned}
ml^2\ddot{\theta}_1&= F_{el} - mgl\tan\theta_1\\
ml^2\ddot{\theta}_2&= - F_{el} + mgl\tan(-\theta_2)\\
\end{aligned}
$$
Where $F_{el}$ contributes to increase the first angle, but decrease the second (adopting positive angle to direction of the first sphere), and the gravitational force contribute to decrease the first angle and increase the second, but it is projected to the line joining both spheres. For small angles, $\tan\theta\approx \theta$ and
$$
\begin{aligned} 
ml^2\ddot{\theta}_1&=F_{el}-mgl\theta_1\\
ml^2\ddot{\theta}_2&=-F_{el}-mgl\theta_2
\end{aligned}
$$
Subtracting both equations and defining $\phi=\theta_1-\theta_2$ as the whole angle between the spheres, we subtracting both equations to get
$$
ml^2\ddot\phi = 2F_{el} -mgl\phi
$$
In equilibrium, the total angle between both particles should be constant, which means $\ddot\phi =0$. By symmetry, they should be equal, so $\phi=2\theta$ and we get
$$
2F_{el} = mgl\phi = 2mgl\theta \approx 2mgl\tan\theta
$$
From which the result follows.
